# Java program is extremely slow while the task is pretty simple

Tags: java, performance, file-io, classification, bufferedreader

I made a classifier where you first train the classifier with one folder full of texts a class A and then a folder full of texts of class B. After that you give the classifier a test-text and the classifier should guess the right class A or B (or C or D... if you have more categories).

However, this program is somehow extremely slow while it should take only a couple of seconds, it takes more than 10 minutes. I think the fault is somewhere in the Reader because I set timers between steps so I could find it out. The thing I found out is that these two methods are probably causing the problem:

```
public String readText(String path) {
    BufferedReader br;
    String result = "";
    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));


        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append("\n");
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        result = sb.toString();
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    return result;
}
```

This is the method reading the text of one path and giving the result. (above)

```
    public void handleTrainDirectory(String folderPath, Category category) {
    File folder = new File(folderPath);
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    for (File file : listOfFiles){
        if (file.isFile()) {
           handleTrainText(file.getPath(), category);
        }
    }

}
```

This thing loops through the entire folder I give and does all the things that are needed per text. (above)

```
   public void handleTrainText(String path, Category category) {
    String[] text = handleText(path);
    makeVocabulary(text);
    List<Integer> wordFrequencies = countWordFrequencies(text);
    Text newText = new Text(path, category, wordFrequencies);
    trainTexts.add(newText);
}
```

This is what handleTrainText does with every text. (above)

To make this post not too long I won't give here all the methods because I think the failure is somewhere in one of these methods. If you want to see one of the other methods I give them immediately but for now I try to make this post as clear as possible.

FYI: I'm doing this for one directory with only 300 small text-files in it single threaded and it should take only a few seconds.

PS: sorry for my terrible English, not my native language.

EDIT: because it's not really clear for you guys what happens here are some other methods which are called by handleTrainText:

```
public String[] handleText(String path) {
    String text = readText(path);
    String normalizedText = normalizeText(text);
    return tokenizeText(normalizedText);
}

public String normalizeText(String text) {
    String fstNormalized = Normalizer
            .normalize(text, Normalizer.Form.NFD)
            .replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "")
            .toLowerCase()
            .replace("\n", "")
            .replaceAll("[0-9]", "")
            .replaceAll("[!?;:,.%]", "");


    return fstNormalized;
}
public String[] tokenizeText(String normalizedText) {
    return normalizedText.split(" ");
}
public List<String> makeVocabulary(String[] tokens) {
    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++)
        if (!vocabulary.contains(tokens[i]))
            vocabulary.add(tokens[i]);
    return vocabulary;
}
```

Comment: My suggestion is to feed the stream directly to the parsing logic, there is no need to hold all this in memory. The issue may be frequent GCs after you load multiple files.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, do all the functionality of the program in one big method? Makes that Java faster?

Comment: I didn't finish looking at your code, but there is *never* a need to have one big method since you can always split one into many `final` methods that chain-call each other.

Comment: Wat is 'GCs' searched on Google, but no logic result :-). Sorry guys, i'm a beginner.

Comment: GC stands for [Garbage Collector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)). It's responsible for cleaning unused (dereferenced) objects from the memory.

Comment: Without seeing more on what method call which it's hard to tell where the problem is. My guess would be that you are keeping more things in memory than you need to, or possibly creating many strings. I suggest you perform benchmarks to find out which part of the program is slow.

Comment: @TotalCare I'm unsure what handleText does. I assume it calls readText. You are holding on the the text memory in the StringBuilders, instead of using them to build your vocabulary directly. Depending on your algorithm, countWordFrequencies and makeVocabulary make take a while. Please print the time that these take to complete between interations.

Comment: Like this?  `long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();` and after the method `long finishTime = System.currentTimeMillis();` plus `System.out.println("That took: "+(finishTime-startTime)+ " ms");` or is this not accurate enough? If not, what should I use to do a benchmark test?

Comment: @TotalCare I think Razvan is asking for the time for each iteration. Sour print the time for each file. Eg at the beginning and end of handleTrainText. You may find that it takes longer and longer to process filesas resources are consumed.

Comment: Done exactly like you told me, here are the results: the first are all 20-40 ms and after like 25 it goes up to 80 ms, after 50 it goes up to 120 ms etc. How can I make that it stay all the same? I stopped the program and the last one (think there were like 200 of them) the timer was already on 240 ms per step.

Comment: I think the way I test is bullshit, it gives 300 ms after a certain time, but that would be 3 seconds. However, every 0,7 second there is coming a new result so the way I test is total nonsense. However, even after one directory is done the second directory it doesn't start again but the time still adds up. Thats why it's so super slow. Any idea how I can make this faster? After 400 texts the timer is now on 600ms already!

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer: your `makeVocabulary` method is `O(n^2)`; Replace it with

```
public Set<String> makeVocabulary(String[] tokens) {
    return new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(tokens));
}
```

Of course, I would really suggest you don't read the whole thing at once and instead just do some stream processing. Remember, on most architectures a cache miss is approximately worth 16-64 other operations...